# Efficiently loop through a file with a fixed length record string using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file that has a fixed length record with no newline characters.

Example: A file with 100 characters that has a fixed length record of 25 characters. (total of 4 records)

How can I read the file per record without having to store the data in a variable. (please see example below)

```
open my $fh, "<", "inputfile.txt" or die "can't open file\n";

my $data = <$fh>; # I would like to avoid storing the file contents in a variable

for (my $j = 0; $j < length $data; $j += 25 ) {

    my $record = substr($data, $j, 25) # Get one record
    print "$record\n";


}
```

2nd option:

I can also use $_ to capture the data in . Am I doing the same thing as above in terms of consuming additional memory?

```
open my $fh, "<", "inputfile.txt" or die "can't open file\n";

while ( <$fh> ) {

    for (my $j = 0; $j < length $_; $j += 25 ) {

        my $record = substr($_, $j, 25) # Get one record
        print "$record\n";
    }
}
```

The reason that I do not wan't to store it in a variable because I am concerned that if I am dealing with a very large file, it would consume twice as space as opening the file.

Am I making the correct assumption that I would be taking twice the space in memory as I did when I opened the file?

What would be the most efficient way to read the file wihtout having to consume a lot of memory?

Please correct me if my question does not make sense.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know the encoding of the file? Do you know the characters per record, or the bytes per record?

Comment: The file in EBCDIC format with packed decimals. Well I am dealing with bytes and I am referring to 1 byte = 1 character. Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That should work, I guess. Otherwise you'd need to set the encoding when opening the file. Both Sobrique's and my answer should work for you.

Comment: I will be adding another option to my question. I am hoping you can give me some feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: The `while` loop is no different from your first option, just that it would read more than one line. But if there is only one, you essentially have the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`read`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) to read a specific number of *characters* from a file handle.

> Attempts to read LENGTH characters of data into variable SCALAR from the specified FILEHANDLE. Returns the number of characters actually read, 0 at end of file, or undef if there was an error (in the latter case $! is also set). SCALAR will be grown or shrunk so that the last character actually read is the last character of the scalar after the read.

Here's a short example.

```
while (read(\*DATA, my $record, 3)) {
    print $record, "\n";
}

__DATA__
foobarbazqrr
```

This will output

```
foo
bar
baz
qrr
```

---

If you read the whole file (as one line) at once, the space you would take up in memory would be at the size of the entire file. It would only be double the size of reading one record at a time if the file only has two very long records.

Comment: When `$/` is scalar ref, does it respect file encoding?

Comment: @Сухой27 I don't know. Using `$/` instead of `read` is an alternative. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2f says it needs the system to understand record-oriented files. I have no idea what that means. `local $/ = 3; say while (<DATA>);` works for my example on my machine. You should add that as an answer. It's the more Perlish way to do this.

Comment: @Сухой27 I tried with setting `DATA` to `Բարեւ աշխարհ` and then reading with the example from the above comment with and without `use utf8`. Without, it breaks the Armenian chars into bytes. With `use utf8` it reads and prints them correctly (but throws wide character warnings because STDOUT is not utf8).

Comment: This is probably the closest on what I am looking for. :)

Comment: I tried this but I am having problems when reading each record. I believe that there are some part of my data getting treated as multibyte utf-8 so it does not capture only 25 bytes. I have set use utf8 in my code.

Comment: The for loop above I mentioned works above but I had to modify it as
my $record = substr($data, $j, 25, -1);

Comment: Made an error in my record count. Works great thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As it's not mentioned yet - check out `$/` - the record separator.

By default, it's linefeed `"\n"` and you read a file line by line.

However, you can set it to a *reference* to a numeric value - it has to be a reference, so it doesn't treat the literal string '25' as the delimiter.

Like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


local $/ = \25;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   print;
   print "\n-- end of record --\n";
}

__DATA__
1234567890123456
12345636734345345345q34523 3 2134234213 35r25253 25252 2524gfartw345sadgw54723wqu745ewsdf
```

Comment: We discussed this approach briefly in the comments on my answer. Maybe you can answer Сухой27's question there.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, as my 'testing-for-SO' setup doesn't really do UTF-8 meaningfully. 

I'll see if I can fettle it into a workable form. It _does_ say "characters" rather than "bytes" though.

Comment: Is your setup more elaborate than my _scratch.pl_ file that keeps getting bigger with every question? :)

Comment: Well, more that TextPad on Windows doesn't do UTF-8 all that well, and my Linux environment is network-isolated.

Comment: I used to use PSPad when I was on Windows, which did all kinds of encoding really well, until I switched to Komodo IDE, which I took with me to Linux.

Comment: I couldn't use this since my record separator is stored in a variable. local $/ = \$rowcount;

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is partly true. Reading the whole file into memory will require as much memory as the file itself uses. For example, if your file is 100 MB, reading it into memory will increase your memory use by 100 MB. This does not mean *twice*, because just opening the file does not require 100 MB.

As for the best way of reading the file record-by-record, this is it:

```
my $record_size = 25;
open my $fh, "<", "inputfile.txt" or die "can't open file\n";
while(read($fh, my $record, $record_size)) {
    print($record."\n")
}
```

Also, consider opening your file in binary mode if it contains anything else but text.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I meant with regards to memory consumption.